# Why ReactJS is not interpreting HTML?

Tags: reactjs, express, mern

I am creating a blog application using the MERN stack. I have used the useState to store get variables. But the output comes with the HTML tag associated with it.

Here is what I have tried:

```
    export default function ShowBlog(){      
           const [eBlog,setEblog]=useState('');

           useEffect(()=>{
                           axios.get('/adminDashboard/blogs/show_blog/?blgId='+id)
                          .then(response=>{
                          if(response.data.flag==="1"){
                             setMsg1("Blog Found.....");
               }else{
                     setMsg1("Could Not Find Blog,Please Try Again.....");
                     return;
               }  
               setEblog(response.data.eBlog);
               
        })
         .catch(error=>{
               setMsg1("Something Went Wrong, Please Try Again.....");
        });
   },[]);


     function BlogContent(){
       return(<>
              {eBlog}

    </>);
    }
```

I am getting the output as `<p>This is...</p>`.